# Не работает скрипт поблочной прокрутки в Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Сразу скажу, что в вопросе я не шарю от слова совсем и этим заниматься не должен. Возникла необходимость прикрутить к сайту поблочный скроллинг, брал исходник отсюда https://gnatkovsky.com.ua/kak-i-gde-podklyuchit-skript.html

Код скрипта

```html
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1280px)");
var anchors = [];
var currentAnchor = -1;
var isAnimating  = false;


$(function(){

    function updateAnchors() {
        anchors = [];
        $(".anchor").each(function(i, element){
            anchors.push( $(element).offset().top );
        });
    }

$("body").on("mousewheel", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
return true;
}  
        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        isAnimating  = true;
        if( e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ) {
            currentAnchor--;
        }else{
            currentAnchor++;
        }
        if( currentAnchor > (anchors.length - 1) 
           || currentAnchor < 0 ) {
            currentAnchor = 0;
        }
        isAnimating  = true;
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: parseInt( anchors[currentAnchor] )
        }, 900, "swing", function(){
            isAnimating  = false;
        });
    });
    updateAnchors(); 

});
```

Работает во всех браузерах, кроме мозиллы. 
Помогите, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

У Firefox название события прокрутки отличается от остальных

```
// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
$("body").addEventListener("mousewheel", ...);

// Firefox
$("body").addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", ...);
```

По-этому нужно вынести тело обработчика события в отдельную функцию и навешать на нее оба названия события

```html
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1280px)");
var anchors = [];
var currentAnchor = -1;
var isAnimating  = false;


$(function(){

    function updateAnchors() {
        anchors = [];
        $(".anchor").each(function(i, element){
            anchors.push( $(element).offset().top );
        });
    }

    function wheelEvent(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (mediaQuery.matches) {
            return true;
        }  
        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        isAnimating  = true;
        if( e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ) {
            currentAnchor--;
        }else{
            currentAnchor++;
        }
        if( currentAnchor > (anchors.length - 1) 
           || currentAnchor < 0 ) {
            currentAnchor = 0;
        }
        isAnimating  = true;
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: parseInt( anchors[currentAnchor] )
        }, 900, "swing", function(){
            isAnimating  = false;
        });
    }

    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    $("body").on("mousewheel", wheelEvent);
    // Firefox
    $("body").on("DOMMouseScroll", wheelEvent);

    updateAnchors(); 
});
```

Comment: Попробую сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало, можешь подсказать почему анимация в ff может дергаться?

Comment: @Pavel, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как верный. На счет анимации - лучше, наверное, создать отдельный пост с вопросом